# What's the adjective used to qualify a software that's available on your first boot?

Tags: word-request

What's the adjective used to qualify a software that's available on your first boot? By that, I mean a software that's available on a machine as soon as you boot the system. Is there an adjective for it? There has to be some word for it, because they are annoying and people uninstall them often whether on smartphone or their PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pre-installed software", or "bundled software" (because it comes in a "bundle" with  the operating system)

But you don't mean "available on boot", you mean "available from when you purchase the computer".  Booting is the process of starting up the computer. You boot the computer many many times. Every time you turn off the computer you need to boot it when you start it again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something different by 'boot' than I would assume; for me, booting refers to every time you start the system, whether you just purchased the device or whether it's already a few years old.

Such software is called *pre-installed software*, *bundled software*, or if you want a term with negative connotations, *bloatware*.

> **Pre-installed software** (also known as **bundled software**) is software already installed and licensed on a computer or smartphone bought from an original equipment manufacturer (OEM).

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-installed_software))